# Postgres failover Error

Tags: postgresql-9.4

We are testing Postgres failover. After the primary brought down, I 'touch' the trigger_file as instructed. The slave now becomes the primary. Test insert statement in the former_slave (now primary) came back with the following error.  Anybody knows what other parameter(s) I need to disable or turnoff?

```
formetest=# insert into tcompany values(50,'NOT ACME','ToonLand1');  
^CCancel request sent  
WARNING:  canceling wait for synchronous replication due to user request  
DETAIL:  The transaction has already committed locally, but might not have been replicated to the standby.  
INSERT 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You got your server in synchrounous commit, that means is waiting to a response from slave(s) and ins‘t get it, deactive the `synchronous_commit` or configure a slave to respond, a extension recommended to failover and switchovers is repmgr